# delete gap between uicollectionview cells

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want create a news application. I designed my storyboard [in this case](http://postimg.org/image/t5pdrzwk5/) and the results is like [this image](http://postimg.org/image/gafbpr58j/). How could delete gap between cells?
this is my code. In this code i have a collection view and two different row called `firstrow` and `secondrow`

```
@interface cillectionview ()
{
    NSMutableArray *images;
    NSMutableArray *titles;
    NSMutableArray *items;
    NSMutableArray *newssurls;
    NSMutableArray *namesOftags;
    NSString *liveurl;
    AppDelegate *appDelegate;
    int imgindex ;
}
@end

@implementation cillectionview
@synthesize mids,collectionView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x303030);

//    
//    collectionView.delegate = self;
//    collectionView.dataSource = self;
    [collectionView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *collectionViewLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;

    collectionViewLayout.collectionView.delegate =self;
    collectionViewLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    collectionViewLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
    collectionViewLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0;

    UIBarButtonItem *liveItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"liveitem@2x.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(showLive:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *tagItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tagitem@2x.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(tagScreen)];


    UIButton *button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hispan@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 51)];
    UIBarButtonItem *logoButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = logoButton;
    logoButton.enabled = NO;


    [liveItem setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    [tagItem setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];

    NSArray *actionButtonItems = @[liveItem, tagItem];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = actionButtonItems;



    items = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    images = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    titles = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    mids = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    newssurls = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    imgindex = 0;

    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    liveurl = [appDelegate getlivelink];
    mids = [appDelegate mIds];
    titles = [appDelegate mTitles];

    for (int i =0 ; i<[mids count]; i++) {
        NSMutableString* aUrl;
        if(i%3 == 0){
         aUrl = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"http://hispantv.com/services/news.asmx/ContentsByCategory?category=%d&count=%d&imagesize=xl",[mids[i] intValue],1];
        }else{
         aUrl = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"http://hispantv.com/services/news.asmx/ContentsByCategory?category=%d&count=%d&imagesize=l",[mids[i] intValue],1];
        }
        contentHelper *helper =[[contentHelper alloc]initWithDelegate:self  mainQuery:aUrl];
        [items  addObject:[helper newss]];
    }

    for (int i =0 ; i<[mids count]; i++) {
        NSMutableString* Url;
        Url = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"http://hispantv.com/services/news.asmx/ContentsByCategory?category=%d&count=%d&imagesize=l",[mids[i] intValue],20];
        [newssurls  addObject:Url];
    }


    for (NSArray *n in items) {
        [images addObject:[n[0] image]];
    }


}


////////////



////////////

- (void)tagScreen
{
    [appDelegate createtag];
    namesOftags =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *names = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *ids = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    namesOftags = [appDelegate GetTagName];


    for (NSMutableDictionary *strdic in namesOftags) {
        [names addObject:[strdic objectForKey:@"name"]];
        [ids addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[strdic objectForKey:@"id"]intValue]]];
    }

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    TagTableViewController *navigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TagTableViewController"];
    //navigationController.titleText = self.titleText;
    navigationController.cellTitles = names;
    navigationController.cellIds = ids;
    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
    [appDelegate GetChild:@""];

}


-(void) getContent:(NSMutableArray *)array{
    self.newss = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.newss = array;
    //

    for (News *n in self.newss) {
        //NSLog(n.title);
    }
    NSLog(@"getcount:   #%i",[_newss count]);
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 6;
}



- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *identifier;




    switch (indexPath.row ) {
        case 0:
            imgindex =0;
            break;
        case 1:
            imgindex =0;
            break;
        case 2:
            imgindex =1;
            break;
        case 3:
            imgindex =1;
            break;
        case 4:
            imgindex =2;
            break;
        case 5:
            imgindex =2;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    if(indexPath.row %2 == 0 ){
     identifier = @"Cell";
        firstrow *cell = (firstrow*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        [cell.bigimg setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:images[indexPath.row + imgindex ]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
        cell.bTitle.text = titles[indexPath.row + imgindex];
        cell.bigimg.tag = indexPath.row + imgindex ;


        UITapGestureRecognizer *rtapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                  initWithTarget:self action:@selector(bigimagetouchesBegan:)];
        [rtapRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];

        [rtapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
        cell.bigimg.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [cell.bigimg addGestureRecognizer:rtapRecognizer];

        return cell;

    }else {

        identifier = @"smallCell";
        secondrow * cell = (secondrow *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell.leftimg setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:images[indexPath.row + imgindex ]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
        cell.lTitle.text = titles[indexPath.row + imgindex];
        cell.leftimg.tag = indexPath.row + imgindex ;
        imgindex ++;
        cell.rTitle.text = titles[indexPath.row + imgindex];
        [cell.rightimg setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:images[indexPath.row + imgindex ]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
        cell.rightimg.tag = indexPath.row + imgindex ;
        imgindex ++;

        UITapGestureRecognizer *rtapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                 initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rtouchesBegan:)];
        [rtapRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];

        [rtapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
        cell.rightimg.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [cell.rightimg addGestureRecognizer:rtapRecognizer];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *ltapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                 initWithTarget:self action:@selector(ltouchesBegan:)];
        [ltapRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
        [ltapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
         cell.leftimg.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [cell.leftimg addGestureRecognizer:ltapRecognizer];


        return cell;
    }
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDelegate

-(void) rtouchesBegan:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gr
{
    UIImageView *theTappedImageView = (UIImageView *)gr.view;
    NSInteger tag = theTappedImageView.tag;
    NSMutableArray * a = [[NSMutableArray alloc ]init];

    contentHelper *helper =[[contentHelper alloc]initWithDelegate:self  mainQuery:[newssurls objectAtIndex:tag]];
    a =[helper newss];


    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    PageContentViewController *navigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contentViewController"];
    navigationController.newss = a;
    navigationController.titleText = [titles objectAtIndex:tag];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:navigationController];
    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
-(void) ltouchesBegan:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gr
{
    UIImageView *theTappedImageView = (UIImageView *)gr.view;
    NSInteger tag = theTappedImageView.tag;
    NSLog(@" %d",tag);
    NSMutableArray * a = [[NSMutableArray alloc ]init];

    contentHelper *helper =[[contentHelper alloc]initWithDelegate:self  mainQuery:[newssurls objectAtIndex:tag]];
    a =[helper newss];


    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    PageContentViewController *navigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contentViewController"];
    navigationController.newss = a;
    navigationController.titleText = [titles objectAtIndex:tag];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:navigationController];
    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
-(void) bigimagetouchesBegan:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gr
{
    UIImageView *theTappedImageView = (UIImageView *)gr.view;
    NSInteger tag = theTappedImageView.tag;
    NSLog(@" %d",tag);
    NSMutableArray * a = [[NSMutableArray alloc ]init];

    contentHelper *helper =[[contentHelper alloc]initWithDelegate:self  mainQuery:[newssurls objectAtIndex:tag]];
    a =[helper newss];

    NSLog(@"number is #%i",[a count]);


    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    PageContentViewController *navigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contentViewController"];
    navigationController.newss = a;
    navigationController.titleText = [titles objectAtIndex:tag];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:navigationController];
    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need: 1. Override standard flow layout. 2. Add implementation like that:

```
- (NSArray *) layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSArray *answer = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];

    for(int i = 1; i < [answer count]; ++i) {
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *currentLayoutAttributes = answer[i];
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *prevLayoutAttributes = answer[i - 1];
        NSInteger maximumSpacing = 4;
        NSInteger origin = CGRectGetMaxX(prevLayoutAttributes.frame);
        if(origin + maximumSpacing + currentLayoutAttributes.frame.size.width < self.collectionViewContentSize.width) {
            CGRect frame = currentLayoutAttributes.frame;
            frame.origin.x = origin + maximumSpacing;
            currentLayoutAttributes.frame = frame;
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
```

where maximumSpacing could be set to any value you prefer. This trick guarantees that the space between cells would be EXACTLY equal to maximumSpacing.

hope this will help you.

Updated answer:

```
#pragma mark Collection view layout things
// Layout: Set cell size
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"SETTING SIZE FOR ITEM AT INDEX %d", indexPath.row);
    CGSize mElementSize = CGSizeMake(104, 104);
    return mElementSize;
}
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 2.0;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 2.0;
}

// Layout: Set Edges
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
   // return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,8,0,8);  // top, left, bottom, right
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0);  // top, left, bottom, right
}
```

Use this.

Comment: when i insert [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect]; in my code it return me an error : No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:'

Comment: I write this snip of codes but it show me half of first cell like this link.http://postimg.org/image/5ns327enb/